# Optimization with contraint

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

Given the value K with constraint x+y = K, what can be the maximum value of x*y be?
How did they derive this answer?
It is equivalent to finding the maximum value of x*(K-x), which will happen when x = K/2 if x is even and x = gif(K/2).gif = greatest increasing function.

Also what is the greatest increasing function?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vishwa's hint is the most general way of solving constrained optimization problem. From your question I'm assuming (though this was never stated explicitly) that you are looking for only *integer* solutions $x, y$ which complicates things.

For your simple problem, the way you wrote is absolutely the right way to go. You can solve for $y$ so you might as well do so and substitute it into your objective function to get the unconstrained problem
$$\max_x\ x(K-x)$$

This is a quadratic function, which has a single unique maximum and decreases monotonically in both directions. You can use this special structure to find the integer solution you need: first find the maximum over the reals, which you can do using calculus (differentiate and set equal to zero), arguing from symmetry, or by remembering the formula from geometry class, to get $x = K/2$. Because we know that the parabola decreases in both direction from this $x$ (and only because we have this special knowledge!) computing the integer maximum is also easy: we look for the first integer to the left, and to the right, of $K/2$ and take whichever makes the objective function biggest.

If $K$ is an integer and even, $K/2$ is already an integer so is the final solution.
If $K$ is an integer and odd, the nearest integers above and below are $(K+1)/2$ and $(K-1)/2$. By symmetry, both of these give the same value of the objective function so *both* are the solutions to your problem.

PS: I've never heard of the "greatest increasing function." Perhaps you meant "greatest *integer* function," sometimes also called the *floor* $\lfloor x\rfloor$ which returns the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use Lagrange Multipliers

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity 
$$xy=\frac{1}{4}\left((x+y)^2-(x-y)^2\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(K^2-(x-y)^2\right).\tag{1}$$
Since $(x-y)^2\ge 0$, for given $K\ge 0$ the left side of (1) reaches a maximum when $x=y=\frac{K}{2}$, and that maximum value is ${K^2}{4}$.

Suppose now that $K$ is an integer, and $x$ and $y$ are constrained to be integers. If $K$ is even, we can make $x=y=\frac{K}{2}$. But if $K$ is odd,  then the smallest possible value of $(x-y)^2$ is $1$, and the maximum value of $xy$ is therefore $\frac{K^2-1}{4}$.